# Executing an ant script with name changed

Tags: ant

As we know,by default, ant config file name is build.xml .Can we use any other name as config file. If yes, how can we execute such an ant script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
ant -f your_file.xml
```

Try executing `ant -h` or see the [Ant Manual](https://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#commandline) to see the usage for the command.